# Maps for Planning Daily Itineraries

Tags: gps, google-maps

I am trying to use google 'My Maps' to build daily itineraries and have them accessible offline. Saved 'My Maps' are accessible in Google Maps via a diminutive button under the 'saved' menu, however seemingly without a offline functionality. Alternatively would be to export the kmz file and use it within another app such as OsmAnd. However, this would be easier automatically synced with changes without needing to download a static version of the map. (Network-linked kmz files currently not supported). Has anyone found a workable solution for what ought be a common and intuitive use of maps API / GUI?